# Convert Python2 iterkeys() to python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have this line from python2 code:

```
m = w.iterkeys().next();
```

When trying to run this, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'
```

I found out that `iterkeys` is not supported in Python3.

How to convert this line, in order to be compatible with Python3?

Comment: did you try "".keys()"" instead of iterkeys()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist tool for such conversion called [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) let say you have `code.py` file with content as follows

```
import collections
w = collections.OrderedDict(a=1,b=2,c=3)
m = w.iterkeys().next();
print m
```

then open terminal and do `2to3 -w code.py`, this does alter `code.py` to

```
import collections
w = collections.OrderedDict(a=1,b=2,c=3)
m = next(iter(w.keys()));
print(m)
```

which could be used with `python3`. Original is kept as `code.py.bak`.

Answer (score -1):

In python 3.x:

`m = w.iterkeys().next()`

would be equivalent to:

`m = list(w.keys())[0]`